# Geometric Interpretation of "$A,B\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, there exists a point $a∈A$ such that $∀x∈A,y∈B $ there exists $b∈B$ such that $|a−b|≤|x−y|.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $A,B$ are subsets of the complex plane $C$ with $A$ compact.

Then there exists a point $a∈A$ such that $∀x∈A,\ y∈B $ there exists $b∈B$ such that $|a−b|≤|x−y|$.

This is not a duplicate of [Show that there exists a point $a \in A$ such that for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $|a - b| \le |x - y|$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102287/show-that-there-exists-a-point-a-in-a-such-that-for-all-x-in-a-and-y-in)

I have proved it. I just can't see it geometrically. Can some one help in visualizing what is happening here.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might mean "$A, B \subset \Bbb C$", not "$A, B \in \Bbb C$"; what do you think?

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's just saying that there is a shortest distance between the two sets, specified by the distance between the points $a$ and $b$. In other words, if you were to choose any two points $x\in A$ and $y \in B$, that these two points will be further apart than the distance between $a$ and $b$.

(Of course, if the two sets $A$ and $B$ intersect, then you can just choose $a = b \in A\cap B$, then $|a - b| = 0$. )

Comment: That is true if we assume $B$ to be closed. Otherwise we need to be a bit more careful as such a $b$ with minimal distance might not exist.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I should probably be a little bit more rigorous with the explanation in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @SeanLee It is not your fault. There was a typo in the question. Thanks for your quick response.